# Problema al pasar arreglo de PHP a JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, array

Buen dia a todos, estoy teniendo problemas en pasar el siguiente arreglo, en javascript no me refleja ningun dato, siendo que si los hay desde la consulta SQL

Saludos!

```
    <php>
    $bajoStock = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Descripcion, Cantidad, (Cantidad - Qty_Min) AS diferencia FROM inventario WHERE (Cantidad - Qty_Min) <= 0");
        $arrayDesc = array();
        $arrayQty = array();
        if ($bajoStock){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bajoStock)){
                $itemDesc = utf8_encode($row['Descripcion']);
                $itemQty = utf8_encode($row['Cantidad']);
                array_push($arrayDesc, $itemDesc);
                array_push($arrayQty, $itemQty);
            }
        }
    </php>

<script type="text/javascript">
var itemd = '<?php echo json_encode($arrayDesc);?>';
var itemq = '<?php echo json_encode($arrayQty);?>';

            for (var i = 0; i < itemd.length; i++){
            alert("Producto" +itemd[i]);
            }
</script>
```

Al momento de imprimirse no me arroja ningun resultado de la consulta, alguno sabe cual es el error?

Saludos!

Comment: ¿que es lo que te imprime al hace echo $arrayDesc y echo $arrayQty? posiblemente no haya nada, este mal formado. Además un objeto JSON no se recorre como un array normal si no por sus objetos.

Comment: Me imprime dos alert, uno con el simbolo "[" y otro con "]" y es todo lo que imprime

Comment: Revisa las variables tanto en PHP como en JS, imprimiéndolas, por ejemplo: `console.log(itemd);  console.log(itemq);` o haz un `alert` de los objetos completos fuera del bucle. O en PHP con `var_dump($arrayDesc);  var_dump($arrayQty);` No es lo mismo un objeto JSON que en un array JSON por ejemplo... Es necesario ver lo que está saliendo y qué estructura tiene para saber cómo leerlo.

Comment: Si te imprime corchetes [] es por que es un array vacío. revisa que la consulta esté devolviendo un valor antes de pasarlo a tu script.

Comment: Cambie la consulta, en lugar de comparar "diferencia <= 0" compare la resta, pero ahorta me manda un alert por cada letra de todo la consulta hahaha

Comment: Hice un console.log y me aparece la consulta completa con corchetes y comillas, y tambien me los esta incluyendo como parte del arreglo en JS

Comment: El problema es como estás recorriendo tu respuesta con el for, si actualizas y pones lo que te sale en consola puedo ayudarte a recorrer el array adecuadamente :)

Comment: memoadian, ya esta actualizado el codigo, en el console.log me sale esto ["Teclado Espanol Dell","Toner Xerox 7845 Cian","Toner Xerox 7845 Magenta","Adaptador HDMI - DVI","Cargador Stick Type C"]

Comment: Y me manda un alert por cada caracter, [,",T,e,c.. y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Hay un problema desde el principio con tu código (PHP). Yo usaría un sólo array: `$arr=array();` Luego guardaría así: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bajoStock)){ $arr[]=$row;}` y finalmente: `var items = '<?php echo json_encode($arr);?>';` Y la lectura: `for(var k in items){
  console.log(k + ' - ' + items[k]);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lo pongo aquí por comodidad

si haces esto, asignar $arrayDesk sin comillas simples debería funcionar

¿Por qué? por que con las comillas pasa como un string, los strings son arrays de caracteres y al recorrerlos se parsea 1 x 1, debes pasarlo sin comillas para que js lo interprete como array de strings.

```
var itemd = <?php echo json_encode($arrayDesk) ?>

for (var i = 0; i < itemd.length; i++ ) {
    console.log("Producto" +itemd[i]);
}
```

Comment: Funciono!
Muchas gracias!

Comment: no hay de que  :)